# autocompletion of code taking values from database shows all values from dropdown list

Tags: java

I want to use the autocomplete feature in my custom code editor. I have written this following code but the problem with this code is that it is showing all the values in the dropdown list instead of just those which should match the keyword being typed.

This is the code.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
   public class DbConnect {

        public List<String> completeArea(String query1) {

            ResultSet rs;
            Statement st;
            Connection con;
            PreparedStatement pst;
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/company", "root", "");

                try {
                    query1 = "select * from labels";
                    pst = con.prepareStatement(query1);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        result.add(rs.getString("name"));
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("error occured" + ex);
            }
            System.out.println("size is " + result.size());
            return result;`
        }
    }
```

It would be really helpful if anyone can help me solve this puzzle. I am not a professional and might have made some mistakes. Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: The query doesn't filter anything. It returns all label names of the table. The param query is never used either. Concerning the UI, that is still another question. You should spit your issue into multiple parts and try to correct each part individually. Trying to solve all at the same time with rather limited knowledge is just not the right way.

Comment: I just want that it should only show the result related to the alphabets that are typed instead of the whole list. How can I get that? If you could please help me with that. which functions can I use?

Comment: @davidxxx Sorry, that is not query. It is query1. I will update the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL must be parametrized. `name LIKE 'ab%'` would find all names starting with "ab".

```
    public List<String> completeArea(String inputName) {

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            String query1 = "select name from labels where name like ? order by name";
            try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mysql://localhost/company", "root", "");
                    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query1)) {

                pst.setString(1, inputName + "%");
                try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {}
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        result.add(rs.getString(1));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("error occured: " + ex);
        }
        return result;`
    }
```

The use try-with-resources would result in automatic closing con, pst, rs - even on exceptions, breaks or returns.

The placeholder `?` is filled in as apostrophe, escaped name, % and apostrophe: for instance `name` being `"d'Or"` as `'d''Or'` or such.

Here `select *` would unnecessarily cause more data in the result set, and `select name` allows `rs.getString(1)`, by 1 based index rather than by column label.

A fail-fast version, which throws an exception on error:

```
    public List<String> completeArea(String inputName) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            String query1 = "select name from labels where name like ? order by name";
            try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mysql://localhost/company", "root", "");
                    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query1)) {

                pst.setString(1, inputName + "%");
                try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {}

                    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        result.add(rs.getString(1));
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `rs.getString(1)`  really more efficient than `rs.getString("name")` ?

Comment: Minimally  I think, assuming some mapping from column name to column index happens. Neglectable, and `getString("name")` is more clear. However `select *` can be hugely slower.

Comment: actually, there is not a single alphabet word that I have to fetch. It could be of any alphabet. So I can not write particularly 'ab' or 'c, or 'd'. I mean when the user types a letter at the run time, that particular letter words should be fetched from the database. I can not predefine it.

Comment: (I corrected the variable names a bit.) Now `inputName` is the parameter, the type partial name. And `pst.setString(1, inputName + "%")` then is the LIKE value for searching: all records where the name field _starts with_ inputName, `%` being the wildcard. If you want a "_contains_" autocompletion, `pst.setString(1, "%" + inputName + "%")`

Comment: @JoopEggen  I am sorry but when I use the code that you have provided, the dropdown list of saved names stops coming. In short, the database stops fetching the values.

Comment: As I said, I want it as if the user types 'a' at runtime then words matching with the letter 'a' should display. If user types 's' then words with 's' should display and so on. This is basically for the autocompletion of code.

Comment: You seem to want a query at the beginning with all words, but there is also the technique of multiply asynchrone queries, after every other letter path. You might look at some autocompletion components, like in jquery.

Comment: @JoopEggen in the code that you have provided, what shall come in place of ? so that the same letter word is fetched from database which the user has typed.

Comment: `pst.setString(1, inputName + "%");` will fill in the first (1) `?`, also providing apostrophes and escaping special symbols (like apostrophe). LIKE + yped input name prefix plus SQL wildcard `%` means: all fields starting with input.

Comment: @JoopEggen thank you so very much for your efforts. It really worked. :)